# Delegate one slice of a larger reducer to its own reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a larger reducer, and I want to add another slice to it that will be fairly complicated unto itself.  For example, here's a large, already complex reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
  bigchunk1: { ...someObject },
  bigchunk2: true,
  bigchunk3: [...somevalues],
  bigchunk4: 'etc'
}

function mainReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case Actions.CASE1:
      return {
        ...state,
        bigchunk1: {
           ...state.bigchunk1;
           somevalue: action.payload.this_is_already_enough_nesting
        }
      }
    case Actions.CASE2:
      return {
        ...state,
        bigchunk4: 'this goes on for awhile'
      }
    // lots more cases
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I want to add a new slice to state, so the whole initialState would end up in the store looking like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  bigchunk1: { ...someObject },
  bigchunk2: true,
  bigchunk3: [...somevalues],
  bigchunk4: 'etc',
  newslice: { ...someComplicatedThing }
}
```

But rather than have to write all my new cases into my original reducer (along with a very messy level of nesting and spread operators), I want to write a new reducer that handles just the cases pertinent to `newslice`:

```js
const initialState = { ...someComplicatedThing }

function newSliceReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type}{
    // cases here
  }
}
```

I am aware of `combineReducers`, but I'm having a hard time thinking of how to apply that in this scenario.  `combineReducers` can take these two reducers and place them as siblings, but how can I combine these so that `newSliceReducer` and its associated state becomes a child of `mainReducer` under the name `newslice`?  I feel like this should be simple, but its escaping me right now.  I have been reading the redux docs, but I'm not seeing the answer clearly.  I do not want to use `redux-toolkit` or any outside libraries.

Comment: Could you please clarify why using `combineReducers` and having `mainReducer` as a sibling of `newslice` does not work for you? Are they going have cross-dependencies?

Comment: I am trying to add a slice of state to an already large application and I cannot go rewriting the whole application.  I do not want `newslice` to be a sibling of `mainReducer`, I want it to be a child of `mainReducer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default switch case, you can do

```
      default: 
          let newSlice = newSliceReducer(state.newslice, action)
          if (newSlice !== state.newslice) {
              return {...state,newslice:newSlice}
          }
          return state
```

You can think of Redux as a coding pattern instead of library.

A reducer's job is to update the state and return new object if changed else return old object. If a new object is returned, react assumes something changed and a refresh is triggered.

Now, what you have is a "newSliceReducer" whose state is just a part of main reducer. So, I followed above rules and called the new reducer with state as smaller part of the original state and checked the result if it changed. If yes, I created a new object with updated state else return old state.

It is important to check if newSlice actually changed.